# Find a corresponding value from a data table based on a config table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables `PaymentData` and `PaymentDataConfig`. There is a common column `id`. Table `PaymentDataConfig` has a `configColumn` which contains name of columns from table `PaymentData`.

```
if exists (select 1 from sys.objects o where o.[object_id] = object_id(N'PaymentData'))
begin
    drop table PaymentData 
end

create table PaymentData 
(
    id int,
    payment1 decimal(20,2),
    payment2 decimal(20,2),
    payment3 decimal(20,2),
    payment4 decimal(20,2),
    payment5 decimal(20,2)
)

insert into PaymentData (id, payment1, payment2, payment3, payment4, payment5)
select 1 as id, 1001.00 as payment1, 1002.00 as payment2, 1003.00 as payment3, 1004.00 as payment4, 1005.00 as payment5 union all
select 2 as id, 2001.00 as payment1, 2002.00 as payment2, 2003.00 as payment3, 2004.00 as payment4, 2005.00 as payment5 union all
select 3 as id, 3001.00 as payment1, 3002.00 as payment2, 3003.00 as payment3, 3004.00 as payment4, 3005.00 as payment5 union all
select 4 as id, 4001.00 as payment1, 4002.00 as payment2, 4003.00 as payment3, 4004.00 as payment4, 4005.00 as payment5 union all
select 5 as id, 5001.00 as payment1, 5002.00 as payment2, 5003.00 as payment3, 5004.00 as payment4, 5005.00 as payment5

select * from PaymentData

if exists (select 1 from sys.objects o where o.[object_id] = object_id(N'PaymentDataConfig'))
begin
    drop table PaymentDataConfig 
end

create table PaymentDataConfig 
(
    id int,
    configColumn varchar(1000)
)

insert into PaymentDataConfig (id, configColumn)
select 1 as id, 'payment1' as configColumn union all
select 2 as id, 'payment2' as configColumn union all
select 3 as id, 'payment3' as configColumn union all
select 4 as id, 'payment4' as configColumn union all
select 5 as id, 'payment5' as configColumn

select * from PaymentDataConfig

select p.*, c.* 
from PaymentData p 
join PaymentDataConfig c on p.id = c.id
```

If I join the two tables on id I would get result like following

```
id  payment1| payment2|payment3 |payment4|  payment5|id |configColumn
------------+---------+---------+--------+----------+---+-------------
1   1001.00 | 1002.00 | 1003.00 | 1004.00|  1005.00 |1  |payment1
2   2001.00 | 2002.00 | 2003.00 | 2004.00|  2005.00 |2  |payment2
3   3001.00 | 3002.00 | 3003.00 | 3004.00|  3005.00 |3  |payment3
4   4001.00 | 4002.00 | 4003.00 | 4004.00|  4005.00 |4  |payment4
5   5001.00 | 5002.00 | 5003.00 | 5004.00|  5005.00 |5  |payment5
```

Expected result is as following where across the column name I would like to see the corresponding value

```
id  payment1| payment2|payment3 |payment4|  payment5|id |configColumn|correspondingValue
============|=========|=========|========|==========|===|============|==================
1   1001.00 | 1002.00 | 1003.00 | 1004.00|  1005.00 |1  |payment1    |1001.00
2   2001.00 | 2002.00 | 2003.00 | 2004.00|  2005.00 |2  |payment2    |2002.00
3   3001.00 | 3002.00 | 3003.00 | 3004.00|  3005.00 |3  |payment3    |3003.00
4   4001.00 | 4002.00 | 4003.00 | 4004.00|  4005.00 |4  |payment4    |4004.00
5   5001.00 | 5002.00 | 5003.00 | 5004.00|  5005.00 |5  |payment5    |5005.00
```

Comment: In the above example, I have only shown five payment columns but i have 60 such columns in table PaymentData. This table holds values in range of 5-10 million records.

Comment: Can you tag your SQL Server version?

Comment: added the version number as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CASE expression to achieve this:

```
select p.*, c.*, CASE c.configColumn WHEN N'payment1' THEN p.payment1 WHEN N'payment2' THEN p.payment2 WHEN N'payment3' THEN p.payment3 WHEN N'payment4' THEN p.payment4 WHEN N'payment5' THEN p.payment5 ELSE NULL END AS correspondingValue
from PaymentData p 
join PaymentDataConfig c 
on p.id = c.id
```

As your update mentioned, if you have a lot of configured columns, you can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)=N''
DECLARE @ID int;
SELECT @ID=MIN(ID) FROM PaymentDataConfig;
WHILE @ID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SET @SQL=@SQL+' WHEN N''payment''+CAST(@ID AS nvarchar(20)) +N' THEN p.payment'+ CAST(@ID AS nvarchar(20))';
  SELECT @ID=MIN(ID) FROM PaymentDataConfig WHERE ID>@ID;
END
SET @SQL=@SQL+N'
    select p.*, c.*, CASE c.configColumn '+ @SQL + N' ELSE NULL END AS correspondingValue
    from PaymentData p 
    join PaymentDataConfig c 
    on p.id = c.id'

exec sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: I have sixty such columns, writing it like mentioned will be two cumbersome.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is a good option here, be aware you must enable it, it's off by default (and has some security implications). If you can refactor your data another approach is to store your data in a 4 column format so each "Record" is 60 rows, a RowID, PaymentID, PaymentType (Payment1, Payment2, ...) and finally the actual payment. Then finding the payment matching the Config is just WHERE Payment.PaymentID=Config.PaymentID and Payment.PaymentType=Config.PaymentType. You can rebuild the table style output either with Pivot or if it's in SSRS with a MATRIX format report.